# Join as project member on invent kde

Tags: git

I want to contribute some code and design on this app:
https://invent.kde.org/kde/kdeconnect-android/

But I can't push my code on this repository:
https://invent.kde.org/frdana/kdeconnect-android.git

How to request the owner to add me as a project member?

Comment: Did you read the README? It has [a section on contributing](https://invent.kde.org/kde/kdeconnect-android/#contributing).

Comment: Thanks @curiousdannii. It is helping me. I was confusing to try contribute on the first time.

Oh god, I got vote down as a new contributor.

Comment: @DitaAjiPratama in fairness, you're not a new user to the SE sites, you have nearly thirty badges over on SO; [they also](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) expect people to do their research before posting a question, and to show their research in their question when they do.  If this question gets closed soon, as it may, don't take it to heart: we'd love you to stay around, but you should expect to put a little more effort into your next question.

Comment: @curiousdannii I think it could be an useful answer, and not a close reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to know how you're expected to contribute to the project would be either check project documentation or reach one of the project maintainers.

Many open-source projects have would have some kind of a guideline for new contributors. For the project you're interested in this information is here: https://invent.kde.org/kde/kdeconnect-android/#contributing

Good portion of projects stored on the Github would have `CONTRIBUTING` file with the guidelines.